# What is the point of order preserving estimations of polynomials?

Tags: polynomials

Why do I need to know the OPL and OPU of a polynomial and what's the benefit of it? What concept is it going to lead to in the future? I have to study this topic but I'm not sure what's the purpose of it. When I try to look it up online, I get almost nothing. Some general explanation would help me a lot.

Edit: The topic name that I have to study is "Order Preserving Estimations of Polynomials". I have been provided with a very short explanation. Here's a snippet:

*We would like to examine the behaviour of the values P (x) when x takes great enough positive values. One can make the intuition that when 0 < x is great, then the value P (x) is determined by its dominant term: a^n · x^n , and the ”rest” of P (x) is negligible.*

I understand the reasoning in this snippet. If I want to find the upper estimation of a polynomials, firstly I need to get rid of negative terms if any and then replace every power by the one of the dominant term. Similarly but the opposite for the lower estimation. I want to know what's the purpose of this topic. That's it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: OPL, OPU ? In which close environment do you live ? You have to give the meaning of such acronyms...